# Undefined reference to static member function of a class in a namespace C++

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, namespaces, g++, static-methods

I have created a C++ class to provide methods to manipulate mutex and it is supposed to work on Windows as well as Linux based systems. When I compile this code without enclosing the class in namespace, it compiles and works. But when I enclose it in a namespace, I get a compile time error for all static methods, following is example of one.

> **undefined reference to
>   `mutexns::MutexHandler::Down(pthread_mutex_t*)'**

I have had no luck yet to use this class from within a namespace. Any and all suggestions will be much appreciated. Thank you in advance.

I am using g++ compiler on an Ubuntu 16.04 machine.

> g++ (Ubuntu 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.10) 5.4.0 20160609

Following is the class definition which results in above mentioned compile time error.

```
#ifndef MUTEXHANDLER_H_
#define MUTEXHANDLER_H_

namespace mutexns
{
#ifdef WIN32
#include <windows.h>

#define MUTEX HANDLE

#else
#include <pthread.h>

#define MUTEX pthread_mutex_t

#endif

    typedef enum
    {
        SUCCESS = 0,                    // Operation successful
        ERR_UNKNOWN = -1,               // An unknown error occurred
        ERR_MUTEX_CREATION = -2,    // Error creating mutex
        ERR_MUTEX_LOCK = -3,            // Error acquiring lock
        ERR_MUTEX_UNLOCK = -4,      // Error releasing lock
    } MUTEX_ERROR;

    class MutexHandler
    {
        private:
            MutexHandler ();

        public:

            static MUTEX_ERROR
            Initialize (MUTEX *mutex);

            static MUTEX_ERROR
            Down (MUTEX *mutex);

            static MUTEX_ERROR
            Up (MUTEX *mutex);

            static MUTEX_ERROR
            TryDown (MUTEX *mutex); // Only for Linux
    };
}

#endif /* MUTEXHANDLER_H_ */
```

Comment: Don’t include headers inside your namespace.

Comment: Are the definitions of the static members also in the namespace `mutexens`?

Comment: Show how the functions are defined

Comment: What's wrong with [`std::mutex`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/mutex)?  In contrast to `windows.h` and `pthread.h` that's portable (and doesn't require extra libraries).

Comment: @KhouriGiordano That's a great catch, will remove it.

Comment: @KaiGuther Yes, static members are also in namespace mutexns

Comment: @HenriMenke That's a great advice, will try std::mutex and see if this target supports it. If it works, it may solve my problem.